# Jetty sslConnetor functions?

Tags: ssl, jetty

I configure ssl on jetty. I am using this code:

import org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector;
.
.
.

SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector();
sslConnector.setPort(8054);
sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(30000);

sslConnector.setKeystore("path to keystore..."); 
sslConnector.setPassword("blabla");
sslConnector.setKeyPassword("blabla");

this.jetty.addConnector(sslConnector);

My Q is: why is there a need to set keystorepsw and psw? What does the setPassword set?

Where can aI find API for SslSocketConnector with documentation about the functions? ( cant find one...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setPassword` sets the keystore's password. You'll usually need to set it indeed. Some keystore types are protected by a password (and wouldn't let you open them at all without it), whereas the key password is for loading the key itself. Often, they are the same password, but this might not always be the case.

You can find some documentation on these pages (depending on the version you're using):

- http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/security/SslSocketConnector.html
- http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ssl/SslSocketConnector.html
- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Ssl+Connector+Guide

This link may be of interest too:
[How to run jetty server in SSL mode using PKCS12 keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999758/how-to-run-jetty-server-in-ssl-mode-using-pkcs12-keystore)